# Background-image property not work. It works inline but not with the style sheet

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for 4 hours now to figure out what's wrong. I don't think it's the file path. I'm using `background-image: url("LagoDiBraies.jpg")` because the CSS stylesheet and the image are in the same folder. It works.

Here's my HTML and CSS. I'm so frustrated and tired.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 104rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("LagoDiBraies.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="website-logo-text">
        <p>Xtreme Adventures</p>
      </div>
      <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">Sports</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav_link nav_login_button">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried changed the path multiple times. It's not working. I think I have the right path too,because the image is just in my project folder, and the stylesheet and image are in that same fold. I get an image when I use inline CSS but no image when I try to use the external CSS.

Comment: If the image is in the same folder of your CSS, the path would be `css/LagoDiBraies.jpg`. `url` is relative to your HTML files, but not CSS files.

Comment: Open the developer tools of your web browser. Go to the network tab. Are you seeing a "404" error for your image there? If so, check the URL that failed to load.

Answer (score -7):

Due to the use of this property, the background-image is uploaded quickly and its quality remains intact. You can deliver responsive images by adding size and srcset to normal images. Suppose the background image of your website is in an external CSS file, inline that image with the HTML file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).